# Cross reference IDs to output correct name javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

So to cut this quick, here is what I am trying to do.

I have two JSON outputs and I am looping through all of the data, I can output the item name and website URL successfully, these are working. However, each job has a `department_id` and each department has an id. I can pass both sets of ids but I need to put the correct department with the job, so I need someway of cross-referencing the ids so the department is shown on the correct job.

Here is what I have so far

```
<script>
    (function() {
      const jobPositions = document.getElementById('jobPositions');

      var jobs = $.ajax({
        url : 'https://www.welcomekit.co/api/v1/external/jobs?access_token=redac&organization_reference=redac&websites=true&status=published',
        dataType: 'json'
      });

      var jobDepartments = $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.welcomekit.co/api/v1/external/departments?access_token=redac&organization_reference=redac',
        dataType: 'json'
      });

      $.when(jobs, jobDepartments).done(function(jobs, jobDepartments) {
        var data1 = jobs[0];
        var data2 = jobDepartments[0];

        $.each(data1, function(i, item) {
          var start = i++;
          var jobDept = item.department_id;
          var jobID = data2[i].id;
          var JobDeptName = data2[i].name;

          const dept = jobID === jobDept;
          console.log(jobID, jobDept, dept);

          if(start) {
            $(jobPositions).append('\
            <a target="_blank" href="'+ item.websites[1].url +'" class="jobPosition-item d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">\
              <div>\
                <span class="jobPositions-name">' + item.name + '</span>\
              </div>\
              <div class="right right-info d-flex align-items-center">\
                <span class="jobPositions-profession">' + JobDeptName + '</span>\
                <div class="d-flex">\
                  <img src="/hubfs/www/about/white-icon-arrow.png" height="11" width="11" alt="arrow">\
                </div>\
              </div>\
            </a>\
          ');
          }
        });
      });
    })();
  </script>
```

The code here (I'll reference with comments)

```
//gets the department_id from item
var jobDept = item.department_id

//gets the department id from data2
var jobID = data2[i].id

//gets the name from each department to be used in the HTML
var JobDeptName = data2[i].name;

//This is to see whether both ids match, not sure if this is the right way to do this
const dept = jobID === jobDept;

//outputs everything
console.log(jobID, jobDept, dept);
```

The result I get is this:

[image]

Which displays this

[image]

This is incorrect as both of these jobs are under `10893` so not the right ID, it's also not showing all item responses I assume due too the undefined error but every job has a department.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is, any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here: `var jobID = data2[i].id;`. You apply index of `data1` array to `data2` array. It should be something like this.

```
var job = data2.find(d => d.id === item.department_id);
if(job)
   var jobID = job.id;
```

Comment: I'm still testing your fix, but how would I go about fixing the undefined error?

Comment: `undefined` error in OP comes from the obvious thing: `data1` and `data2` may have different length.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that? Because otherwise not all of the jobs will show.

Comment: See my answer. it doesn't use `data2[i]` in context of `data1.each` so this **is** the fix.

Comment: Oooh sorry my bad, ignore me haha, thanks. Still trying to get my head around JS. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for chasing up but can you explain what `(d => d.id` does? If you don't mind :) I know that `.find()` is searching for the ids but not sure what the beginning part does.